# Change Multiple Form Sizes Django Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style my Django forms using CSS. I want it so that I can have multiple fields on the one line and different widths, but also have some fields that stretch the whole width of the container. I'm finding it difficult to do.

I've tried using Bootstrap's grid system but I can't specify which div to put around which form element. I've also tried using a few answers I've seen here with TextAreas, and specifying the number of rows and cols like so:

```
widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 8, 'rows': 1})
```

I was wondering is there a way I can add divs around particular inputs without having to use lots of if else statements in the template.

I could specify a template with the divs already in it but I'm fairly sure I can only use one form template?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to use [Crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which has support for rendering Bootstrap compatible layout. You can easily define divs and their classes in form's helper. Here's an example with two text fields in one row:

```
class SampleForm(Form):

    name = CharField()
    surname = CharField()

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = layout(
        Div(
            Div('name', css_class='col-sm-6'),
            Div('surname', css_class='col-sm-6'),
            css_class='row'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own width: 20% for 5 cells, 14,28% for 7 cells

```
.col-xs-20, .col-sm-20, .col-md-20,.col-lg-20,/* 5 Cells */{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.col-xs-20{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
 }
.col-sm-20{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.col-md-20{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.col-lg-20{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```